# selectize.js Avoid automatic sort options

Tags: selectize.js

I try to use selectize dynamically via AJAX
So I fetch the needed data and then push them to selectize. But my data have been ordered already and I don't change order. So I use next code

coffeescript:

```
     data # array with payload
     new_opts = []
      $.each data.recipients, (_, value) ->
        new_opts.push({text: value[1], value: value[0]})

      selectize = $('#user_ids')[0].selectize
      selectize.clear()
      selectize.clearOptions()
      selectize.renderCache['option'] = {}
      selectize.renderCache['item'] = {}
      selectize.addOption(new_opts)
      selectize.refreshOptions
```

How can I avoid sorting process inside selectize ?

Thx

Comment: You can set the data element you want selectize to sort by using the `sortField` option or you can override the `$score` function altogether. Check out [the docs](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md).

Comment: How can I rewrite `$score` in my case? Can you help?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you want to do. If you are just trying to sort the data in the same order as you are pushing it into your `new_opts` array, why don't you just add a count to your `$.each` function, push something like `order: [count]` along with your data, and set the `sortField` to `order`?